# Laravel 6 - Consulta no retorna informacion que requiero

Tags: laravel

Nose que titulo colocarle a mi duda, sucede lo siguiente, tengo la siguiente consulta en mi controlador:

```
$data = DB::table('payments')

->leftJoin('users as u', 'payments.user_id', '=',  'u.id' )
->leftJoin('role_user', 'role_user.user_id', '=',  'u.id' )
->leftJoin('roles', 'role_user.role_id', '=', 'roles.id' )
->where('payments.id' , '=', $payment->id)
->select('u.name','payments.vouche', 'roles.name')
->get();

dd($data);
```

Cuando intento traer en mi consulta los campos de las tablas:

USUARIOS = NOMBRE

PAGOS = BONO

ROLES = NOMBRE

Por alguna razón la consulta se confunden y solo me devuelve el nombre del rol, el parámetro(NAME) de la tabla usuarios(USERS) no lo devuelve.

Mi duda es:

Como hago que me devuelva el campo nombre de la tabla usuarios(USERS) sin cambiarle el nombre a dicho campo desde la base de datos.

Anexo algunos captures:

https://prnt.sc/v2s48z

https://prnt.sc/v2s54f

NOTA:

Le cambié el nombre al campo NAME de la tabla usuarios, y si me regresa la información que requiero, ya la consulta tiene alias, pero aun así se confunde, no sé que estoy haciendo mal.

NOTA 2:

Utilice una solucion alternativa pero aun me queda la duda:

En el retorno envio el parametro payment

```
    return view('payments.edit', compact('datas','payment'));
```

Y asi solo retorno lo que necesito sin fallas en la consulta y del parametro payment retonro el nomnbre.

No me parece la mejor solucion, me interesa utilizar las buenas practicas

Comment: ¿entonces la duda radica en darle alias a las columnas en el select?

Comment: Puede ser, el alias ya se lo puse, pero no hace ningún cambio. Por eso mi duda, no se que hago mal si el alias esta bien asignado.

Comment: Ya usaste el alias pero en el Select? Te pregunto por qué no lo veo

Comment: Prueba en el Select así `u.name as Nombreusuario` por cada valor

Comment: pfs era eso, lo agregue asi         `->select u.name as users' ` y retorna el usuario. Muchas gracias. Es buena practica generar asi las consultas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mas allá de si es buena práctica o no, te recomiendo:

- Evita usar nombres tan genéricos para identificar en este caso: columnas de tus tablas
- Dale un alias desde tu `select` a cada una de está forma

  ```
  select(['columna1 as valor1', 'columna2 as valor2', .....])
  ```

Ahora el aspecto anterior fácilmente se evita si no usas cosas tan genéricas como `name` que no termina de identificar que sea el nombre de que....?